# pouchdb limited replication with couchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, progressive-web-apps, pouchdb

I am trying to sync from pouchDB to couchDB with the newest pouchDB/couchDB possibilities.
Upstream should be all docs, downstream only a limited amount. In my PWA (JavaScript WebApp), I have something like this:

```js
pouch.sync('posts', window.remoteDB.url(), {
    auto_compaction: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    skip_setup: false,

    pull: {
        limit: 5  // this does not kick in
    },
    push: {}
});
```

Additionally, I thought about somehow getting filtered-replication into this equation, but I totally don't get the docs. I can't figure out how to use counchDB-filters to limit to the newest 5 docs, ordered by timestamp.

How is this problem solvable?

**edit - working solution (js):**

1. directly post a request to couchDB's `/databaseXYZ/_find` endpoint: `{"selector": {"type": "post"}, "sort": [{"timestamp'2: "desc"}], "limit": 5}` --> to get item number 5's timestamp value as x
2. add a filter-design-document to couchDB: `{"_id": "_design/myfilters","filters": {"newerThen": "function (doc, req) { return doc.timestamp >= req.query.since; }"}}`
3. then do the usual sync, but add a [filter to pull](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtered-replication): `pouchDB.sync(...localdb, ...url, {..., pull: {filter: 'myfilters/newerThen', query_param:{since: x}, push: {/*all*/}}`

Comment: Please specify exact versions, as "latest possibilities" changes almost daily.

Comment: Filtered replication works on document keys, not on a limit. There is no way to limit replication to a specific number of documents (doing so would actually break the replication protocol).

Comment: Leads me to:  getting a list of the newest 5 keys, getting that earliest timestamp and use it in a downstream filtered replication as timestamp>x. Upstream would still be unfiltered. This giving the user a button to sync all. Would that work? Any better solution?

Comment: ... It did work.